# Silencing errors on failures for npm run-script

Tags: node.js, npm

When you run `npm test` and it fails, you get the test outputs + a single error message, like so:

```
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

However, I made a custom script called `lint`, like so:

```
// package.json
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    // ... definition for test ...
    "lint": "./node_modules/jsxhint/cli.js src/",
  }
}
```

Alright, simple enough. But when you run `npm run lint` and it fails, Rather than the nice looking error for `npm test`, you get a massive error message after the output of the linter:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run-script" "lint"
npm ERR! node v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
# and ~15 more lines...
```

Is there a way to silence all this junk so I can have a clean output like the `npm test` script? I see how they caught the error in the `npm` source code, but I don't think I can just add a custom command without forking `npm` like that... Hope I'm wrong!

But if I am, would I be better off just pushing off a task like this to a tool like Grunt? Thanks!

Comment: Very annoying issue. Weird that it is hard to find any discussion about this...

Comment: Was getting annoyed with the same happening using `jscs` as linter in a run-script.

Comment: There are a couple issues about this filed on NPM. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6124 https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8821

Answer (score 28):

Use the npm run `--silent` option:

```
$ npm run --silent test
```

Even less typing if you define a shell alias:

```
$ alias run='npm run --silent'
$ run test
```

Comment: Or ```npm run -s test```

Comment: Doesn't work for the OP's use case.  They want to run `npm run lint` on the command line, and specify in the script entry in package.json, that the lint script should not print the useless message.  For example, one would hope that ` "scripts":{ "tslint": "tslint", "lint": "npm run --silent tslint src/**/*.ts" }` might work.  But no.   The useless noisy message vomits forth.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't care about preserving the return code of the linter process, you can always configure your `package.json` like this:

```
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "lint": "eslint . || true",
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also install `cash-true` if you want this to also work on windows

Answer (score 1):

I've just been trying to figure out the same. Not a perfect answer but it kind of worked to specify linting as a pretest script ([docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html)) like so:

```
// package.json
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    // ... definition for test ...
    "pretest": "./node_modules/jsxhint/cli.js src/",
  }
}
```

Then, when you type in `npm test` the first time, you will only get a single-line error from NPM. Obviously, that means you won't be able to run your tests if you haven't linted.

The other option is to use some kind of third party task runner like Make, [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).

I've only used Make, and I think it's the most painless to set up (at least on OSX and Linux, not sure about Windows).

Create a `Makefile` in your root that looks like so:

```
lint:
    ./node_modules/.bin/jslint ./*.js # or whatever your lint command is

test:
    ./node_modules/.bin/mocha test/*.js # or whatever your test command is

.PHONY: lint test
```

Then type `make test` and `make lint` to run those commands.

Comment: Yeah, for now I've just been using gulp and grunt, it works fine though adds an extra install step for the CLI runners and another command to remember that I'd like to streamline out. Not a big deal but I'll leave the question open to see if anyone comes up with something (and check if there's an issue filed on npm for it :-))

Answer (score 1):

You can silence the errors by [redirecting the stderr](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) to /dev/null. For example:

```
{
 "test": "karma start" (package.json)
}
```

running:

```
$ npm run test 2> /dev/null
```

will now send all npm errors to [/dev/null](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) but normal input will still be visible in the console.

Because the error is thrown by npm, after karma exiting with a non-zero status, doing the following is not enough:

```
 {
     "test": "karma start 2> /dev/null"
 }
```

but you can overcome it by creating another task that calls that task with stderr redirection:

```
 {
     "test": "karma start",
     "test:silent": "npm run test 2> /dev/null" 
 }
```

this will ensure that the **npm** error messages are hidden