# Quiet output on npm-script hook

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

Every time I bump the version of my package, I want to write that version in a file for building purposes.

I made a hook on `postversion` so I can execute my `write-version` script every time the version is pumped (through `npm version`).

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "postversion": "node write-version && git push && git push --tags"
}
```

This works, but I would like to get hide the following output it generates:

**CLI**

```
> npm version patch

> my-package-name@0.1.1 postversion C:\git\my-package-name
> node write-version && git push && git push --tags
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try including the [silent](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#default-configs) flag, (either **--silent** or the shorthand **-s** ) in your script to omit the unwanted output. More info can be found in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426332/how-to-suppress-output-when-running-npm-scripts#34426599)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping I could only silence those two output lines automatically. But I guess this will do for now. Thanks for your input @RobC, much appreciated!