# How to force suppress node error even if ran without --silence flag

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "some-custom-script build"
}
```

where `some-custom-script` is provided by me.

I want to always suppress the `npm ERR` warnings in case the `some-custom-script` exits with `process.exit(1)` even if the user does not do `npm run build --silent`. So running `npm run build` and `npm run build --silent` should both (in case of exit) have the error suppressed.

Comment: maybe redirect the `>2` to another file? So that every time it creates a logfile but doesn't print the errors?

Comment: 2>/dev/null throws stderr away

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress output when running npm scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426332/how-to-suppress-output-when-running-npm-scripts)